# Why does database of db2 HADR standby server deactivate automatically?

Tags: unix, db2, sap

Im trying to configure SAP HADR with the primary and standby server. Configurations seems to be ok but the database of standby server deactivates automatically. When i run the command db2 activate database in the standby server it will successfully activated but after a few seconds database gets deactivated again. And with this scenario, nearsync of logs is not consistent. Please advice what would be the possible cause of deactivation of database.

SAP ECC6.0 DB6 9.1

Answer (score 0):

You don't activate the database on the standby DB. The standby DB is always is rollforward mode. You can check this by typing db2top and them u.

Regards